# How parse JSON from file?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have json file with this this code:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 33940157205526204,
      "user": {
        "id": 548844917,
        "full_name": "DelacruzHayden",
        "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/87947328356424110_1657580247886246_102415570_a.jpg",
        "username": "Noreen Lang"
      },
      ...
  ]
}
```

When I want to parse it:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/home/lumawu/test.json");
        do {
            $medias = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
            foreach ($medias['data'] as $media) {
```

I get the error:

```
[ErrorException]              
Illegal string offset 'data'
```

How to decode it?

Comment: Why did you json_encode your $data first if it's already json encoded ? Why not use just `json_decode($data, true)`  ?

Comment: @JérémyCasper because when i use it i get:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `var_dump($data)` (juste after the file_get_content) return NULL or something else ? if it's NULL, the input json is not valid.

Comment: @JérémyCasper return JSON file, but when I want to use foreach() - get error.

Comment: and var_dump($medias) ? Maybe the data attribute of your array is not where you think it is

Comment: you can also try to `var_dump($medias)` just after the decode to see why it won't get into the foreach. In case it is bad formatting, you can get the reason by calling `json_last_error()`

Comment: Why do you encode before decoding - `json_decode(json_encode($data)` ?

Comment: if you don't show us a relevant json (without `...`) no way to tell if it is valid. In my tests, there was a missing `}` that caused the exact error you tell us, because the decoded JSON was `NULL`. After adding the `}` your code worked all right

Answer (score 0):

In your code you just need to do json_decode($data, true) to get the json string to an array.

If you do both json_decode(json_encode($data, true)),
the **json_encode** will encode the json string and the next **json_decode** will not be able to decode json correctly.

So your code should be something like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/home/lumawu/test.json");
        do {
            $medias = json_decode($data,true);
            foreach ($medias['data'] as $media) {
```